# Ubuntu Server 12.04 vsftpd timeout using external IP

Tags: ubuntu, port-forwarding, vsftpd, file-server

I am having a problem connecting to my Ubuntu 12.04 server with vsftpd using my external IP. Connecting with local IP is successful. I am using FileZilla for the ftp client. I know there is a bunch of stuff online about this but nothing has fixed my problem. I have port 21 forwarded in my router, the vsftpd.conf file is correct I believe. The only thing I can think is that I don't have any passive configurations set, but not sure if I need them. If somebody could please help me with this that would be great. I can provide my vsftpd.conf if needed, and also I can take screenshots of my router config to make sure that is correct also.

Answer (score 0):

Forward also port 20 and then check again. And do the check from public service (if ftp work), because some routers (and ISPs) do not permit you connection to your public IP from inside